# Partial BibLatex entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a bib file which contains an online source. This bib file is used across multiple documents, written at different times, citing this online source. Compilation is done using Biber & BibLatex.

Now I have to adjust the date on the source to properly reflect when I accessed this Ressource. But when I do this in the bib file itself, all my documents now have an incorrect date.

My goal is to set the access date per document, but take all the other data from my bib file. Is there any way to override entry options per document?

Comment: You could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401142/36296 to set up separate entries for every time you access the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I read the title of the question, I immediately thought of the `crossref` feature shown in [What is the Bibtex crossref field used for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401138/35864), which [@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz) already linked in the comments. But for your use case I'd probably prefer a Biber sourcemap to override field values easily from within your `.tex` document.

Compare the value from the `.bib` file (2020-02-02) to the value set by the sourcemap and shown in the output (2023-02-20). Note that the sourcemap only works if a `urldate` is present in the `.bib` entry (it will not add `urldate`s to entries that don't have them yet - that could be done, but would probably be overkill).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=urldate, final]
      \step[fieldset=urldate,  fieldvalue={2023-02-20}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  url       = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto},
  urldate   = {2020-02-02},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, Anne (1972). A Theory on Brontosauruses. London: Monthy & Co. url: https://example.edu/~elk/bronto (visited on 20/02/2023).]

The sourcemap shown here applies to all entries alike. If you need to give different dates for different entries, you can filter by `entrykey`, but of course that might get messy rather quickly

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{\Aelk\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=urldate, final]
      \step[fieldset=urldate,  fieldvalue={2023-02-20}]
    }
  }
}
```

Compare also [biblatex: remove field from specific entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358767/35864).

Comment: Yeah I also forgot about crossrefs ^^' But this solution is way easier to wrap into a simple command in the documentclass which can then be invoked from each document for the required sources.